# How do I ask Visual Studio to run this file with a hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to edit SOMEFILE.cpp in Visual Studio. I'd like to press some hotkey (lets say control shift P) to execute `somecommand arg arg2 SOMEFILE.cpp`. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `Tools` menu and select `Options...` to open the `Options` dialog. Then under `Environment`, look at the `Keyboard` settings. You can assign shortcut keys to commands here.

Comment: Which item do i select for executing a binary from outside of visual studios?

Comment: See if you can find a `Tools.ExternalCommand#` in the list of commands, where `#` is a number.